# What happens to my website when domain name expires

Tags: domains, website-features

I am new to this.

Someone just created my website for me for free, and all I did was to pay for the domain and hosting. My website is new with just around 4 posts.

I cannot complete it because I am not knowledgeable enough and I don't have much time. Also the person who I paid to complete it didn't show up. I decided to let my domain name expire, but now I found out that anyone can sell their domain name or website.

Can I sell my domain name, and what will happen to my website or the contents therein? If I sell my domain, does that mean the ownership of my website and its contents there are also transferred to the person?

Comment: **Yes if you make the site on sale and they buy it, the ownership is transferred to the person who bought the website**

Comment: @TheEeveeLovers is not correct.  Yes you can sell the domain name.  The content might not be included, it depends on the agreement you have struck.  Even with the best domain name, a site with 4 posts is unlikely to be worth much.

Answer (score 5):

A domain name is just an address to a website and independent of the web hosting account and its content - collectively referred to as a website.

When you sell a domain, you grant permission to the purchaser to transfer it to either a new domain registrar or different account at the same registrar. Steps include unlocking the domain if it's locked (to prevent transfers), obtaining the "authorization code" which will need to be supplied during the transfer for confirmation, and any additional steps required by your domain registrar (typically none). There should be information in their FAQ's or knowledge-base detailing the steps to transfer a domain.

Unless you make an agreement with the purchaser of your domain name to also purchase your website's content, then when the domain is transferred none of your website's contents will be displayed. The new domain owner will have to upload content to his/her web hosting account.

So in short, selling a domain name does not mean that you're selling the website and its contents too (unless you offer it as a package deal through a site like Flippa).

Lastly, not described in your question but referred to in its title:  Once your domain name expires and you can't renew it (in the case where it's been sold already), then obviously you can no longer sell it, so don't let it expire if you think it has enough value to sell and warrants the steps to do so. Again, content is independent of the domain name, so could be sold regardless, though not commonly done unless it has significant value.

Answer (score 0):

Web hosting and domain names are separate services.

All websites are IP addresses (`555.555.55.55` for example), and a domain name masks that IP address (`example.com` is easier to remember than `555.555.55.55`).

So when your domain name expires, you will no longer be able to reach your web site using that domain name. Instead, assuming that your web hosting account is active, you would have to use the IP address to access your web site.